# stored procedure with out parameter

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckEmailAvailability]  -- Add the
 parameters for the stored procedure here ( @Email VARCHAR(50)=null,
 @Count int OUTPUT

 ) AS BEGIN     
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.  SET NOCOUNT ON;

     -- Insert statements for procedure here    
     SELECT @Count=COUNT(*) from dbo.tx_UserPersonalDetails where s_Email=@Email


     END
```

I have the following code in my aspx.cs page:-

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_CheckEmailAvailability]", objcon);
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            parm.Value = txtUserName.Text.ToString();
            parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

            SqlParameter parm1 = new SqlParameter("@Count", SqlDbType.Int);
           // parm1.Value = txtUserName.Text.ToString();
            parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
           result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            if (result>0)
            {
                lblAvailText.Text = "Email id is in use";



            }
            else
            {
                lblAvailText.Text = "Email id is Available";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sql)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();

        }
```

When I run the code , I am getting an error as :-

> The formal parameter "@Email" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter,
>   but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Please help me with it.

Comment: You used too much copy/paste and made an error in your variable name for the second parameter direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

to

```
parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

You were setting the wrong SqlParam.

parm is used for the @Email param, which is initially correctly specified as Input, but then when you create parm1, you dont set its direction, you set parm's direction.

That is why you should use good naming conventions.

Comment: ah, copy/paste issues are the worst! I ended up here with approximately the same problem! Tx & 1 up!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way - try to use RETURN -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckEmailAvailability] 
(
    @Email VARCHAR(50)
)
AS BEGIN

    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM dbo.tx_UserPersonalDetails
        WHERE s_Email = @Email
    )

END
```

Comment: As there is a `> 0` constraint in the code EXISTS may be a better alternative

Comment: It's equal. `lblAvailText.Text = string.Format("Email id is {0}", result > 0 ? "use" : "Available");`

Comment: I meant that count(1) is a full table scan

Comment: Generally - no (checked on sql server 2005). If you don't have a clustered index - yes.